# Javascript function in setInterval

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, parentheses

I have the following code:

```
var foo=5;
var los= function (){
    alert(foo);};
setInterval(los, 1000);
```

which works correctly.

If I change it to :

```
var los= function (){
    alert(foo);};
setInterval(los(), 1000);
```

it only executes once with no errors in console.
Can someone explain me why this happens when I include the parentesis after `los` in the `setInterval` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that in JavaScript a function is an object, passed around like any other variable.  So this is a reference to the function:

```
los
```

This, on the other hand, *executes* the function and evaluates to its result:

```
los()
```

So when you do this:

```
setInterval(los(), 1000)
```

You're not setting the interval to the function, but to the result of the function.  So, for example, if the function returns `true` then you're essentially writing this:

```
setInterval(true, 1000)
```

The function executed once, then the interval is repeated for its result.  What you want is to use the function reference itself in the interval:

```
setInterval(los, 1000)
```

That way `setInterval` will execute the function each interval, instead of executing its result (which doesn't do anything).

Answer (score 6):

Because you're executing `los()` and then the result of that (single) execution is passed into the `setInterval` function.

`setInterval` requires a function passed in, not `undefined`, which is what `los` returns. However, it doesn't complain - it just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The `()` you've got in the second one means to **call** the function **before** passing the result to `setInterval`. The parentheses are the operator that explicitly request that a function be called; that's why you put the parentheses around the arguments to `setInterval`, after all.

The name of a function, by itself, is a  valid expression in JavaScript. The value of such an expression is a reference to the function. That's the value that you want when you're setting up an interval timer — you want to tell the system what function to call when the timer expires, so you pass a reference to it.